# Collada never defined in animate()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, three.js

I'm trying to load a collada model by a function called createObject and move my collada by changing its position in the function animate().

What I have tried is to declare a var mario then call init(); and animate();.
In init(); I call the function createObject and in animate, I change its position but the object is never defined since nothing happen in my if(mario !== undefined).

```
var mario;
init();
animate();
```

In init() :

```
createObject(mario,"dae/mario.dae",50,50,50,0,-28,0,0,0);
```

In animate() :

```
requestAnimationFrame( animate );
if ( mario !== undefined ) {
    console.log("working!");
mario.position.z += 1;
}
render();
stats.update();
```

My function createObject() :

```
function createObject(object,src,size1, size2, size3, posX,posY, posZ, rotation,audio){         
            // loading manager
            var loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager(function(){
                scene.add( object );
            });
            // collada
            var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader( loadingManager );
            loader.load( src, function ( collada ) {
                object = collada.scene;
                object.scale.set(size1,size2,size3); 
                object.position.x = posX;
                object.position.y = posY;
                object.position.z = posZ;
                object.rotation.z = rotation;
                object.traverse(function (child) {

                    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                        child.castShadow = true;
                        child.receiveShadow = true;
                    }
                });
                if(audio)
                       object.add(audio);                  
            });                             
        }
```

So the object is loaded, but it does not move and the console.log does not print anything.
Can someone help me please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning your model to the function parameter `object` will not assigned the value to `mario`. I suggest you removed the first argument of your function `createObject()` and assigned `collada.scene` directly to the global variable `mario`. It's the same approach like in this example:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html

Comment: Thank for your answer.

I can do that but if I load many colladas I will repeat the same code too many times don't you think ?

Is there one way to load my collada by one line using a function or I must load it in the function init ?

Comment: I just add this comment because I think you didn't see my comment, thank you :).

Comment: Your original code would not work with multiple Collada files, too. I suggest you use an identical `onLoad()` callback for all of your files. After all files have loaded, use a method like [Object3D.getObjectByName()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.getObjectByName) to select your models from your scene. You can then assign the models to variables and safely animate them in your render loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion !

Comment: Yes it was but I'm not sure to all understand, that's why I have posted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works by doing that in init() :

```
loader.load('dae/mario.dae', function ( collada ) {
                mario = collada.scene;
                setObject(mario,50,50,50,0,-28,0,0,0);
                scene.add( mario );
            } );
```

In my function setObject, I just set the size and position etc.

Is that what you mean saying use an identical onLoad() callback for all of your files ?